# How to handle dataframe column with variable date time formats?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I am pretty new to pandas and I am struggling some dates in columns.

I have a dataframe column with dates in multiple formats, such as
'2021-08-21T06:34:34.909Z'
and
'2021-08-21T06:34:34Z'

Is there an elegant way to remove all the milliseconds?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to convert as `datetime64[s]`:

```
>>> df['Datetime']
0    2021-08-21T06:34:34.909Z
1        2021-08-21T06:34:34Z
Name: Datetime, dtype: object


>>> df['Datetime'].astype('datetime64[s]')
0   2021-08-21 06:34:34
1   2021-08-21 06:34:34
Name: Datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]

# OR

>>> pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime']).dt.floor(freq='S')
0   2021-08-21 06:34:34+00:00
1   2021-08-21 06:34:34+00:00
Name: Datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

Comment: Shouldn't this convert to `datetime64[ns] UTC`? Is the result different to pd.to_datetime?

Comment: @MrFuppes. I updated my answer with `pd.to_datetime`.